# Handling Alert dialog Box in Selenium IE using C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am automating some tests for a webapp written in ASP.NET MVC5 that also uses jQuery. I've been looking around for options on handling an alert confirmation box while using Selenium in IE.

I need to confirm the message on the box, but I do not need to click anything on the dialog. Here is what I have now:

```
public bool IsAlertPresentAndCorrect(string Message)
{
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());

        ReadOnlyCollection<string> Handles = Driver.WindowHandles;
        string ToUse = "";
        foreach (string Handle in Handles)
        {
            if (!Driver.CurrentWindowHandle.Equals(Handle))
            {
                ToUse = Handle;
            }
        }

        IAlert Alert = (IAlert) Driver.SwitchTo().Window(ToUse);
        return Alert.Text.Equals(Message);
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        _driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    }
}
```

I have also tried `IAlert Alert = Driver.SwitchTo().Alert()` and `IAlert Alert = Driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement()` in place of getting the window handle but they are not working either.

The problem has been the exact same no matter what code I use: `OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Alert in Chrome:
[image]

Alert in IE:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the alert?

Comment: Done @SouvikGhosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of alert you don't necessarily have to switch back to the window handle. You can simply switch to alert, perform necessary operation, close the alert.
I modified your code a bit to fetch the alert text in a variable, close the alert pop-up then compare the alert text with the message passed in parameter and return bool value.

```
public bool IsAlertPresentAndCorrect(string Message)
{
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
        string alertText = Driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Text;
        Driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
        return alertText.Equals(Message);
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am still not sure what the problem originally was but this is working